# Exit on application crash

Tags: android, crash, exit

when ever any application crash come I want to exit from the app ? 
How to achieve same. does Android manifest have any provision for same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to register a global [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). This catches all the exceptions that are not handled. Then you can do there what you want. For example close the app, inform the user and send a log to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) or a service like [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com%20BugSense) that solve this problem.