# How can I exit on application crash Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Exit on application crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193136/exit-on-application-crash)

I am using `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` to handle application crash,in the method uncaughtException im calling `System.exit` but the application is not getting killed.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your handler method is not returning. This can prevent Android from terminating the app after it is crashed. The user won't see the "force close" dialog until the handler returns. Please be sure your handler method is returning.

Another possibility is that you are preventing Android from terminating it normally by calling `System.exit()`. don't call `System.exit()`. Android will terminate your application after a crash, after your UncaughtExceptionHandler exits.